# counterexample to the Chern number inequality on Fano manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

We know that if an $n$-dimensional Fano manifold admits a Kahler-Einstein metric, it satisfies the following Chern number inequality
$$nc_1^n\leq 2(n+1)c_2c_1^{n-2}.$$

My question is whether there exists a Fano manifold which does not satisfy this inequality (of course in this case this Fano manifold can not have any K-E metric).
 I calculated some examples which have been famously known that they don't support K-E metrics and find out that all of them still satisfy this inequality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a counterexample is given by $\mathbb{P}_{P}(\mathcal{O}_{P}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{P}(n-1))$ for $n\geq 4$, with $P:=\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. The computation is a bit long but here are the main steps (I hope I didn't make mistakes). Let $h\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ be the class of the tautological bundle, and $f$ the pull back of the class of $\mathcal{O}_{P}(1)$.  Standard computations give
$$c_1(X)=2h+f\qquad c_2(X)= 2n\,hf-\binom{n}{2}f^2\, \quad\mbox{ hence }$$
$$\Delta :=2(n+1)c_2-nc_1^2=4n\,hf - n^3f^2\ .$$
I want to prove $\Delta .c_1^{n-2}<0$. This is a sum of terms $\Delta .h^pf^{n-2-p}$ with positive coefficients. Note that $h^2=(n-1)hf$ (Chern class relation), so $h^pf^{n-2-p}=(n-1)^{p-1}hf^{n-3}$ for $p\geq 1$. Then 
$$\Delta .hf^{n-3}=4n(n-1)-n^3\qquad \Delta .f^{n-2}=4n\ .$$
For $n\geq 4$ all the terms are highly negative except $\Delta .f^{n-2}$, one sees immediately that the sum is negative.

Comment: to abx:Thank you very much! Your calculation is correct! I also found out this example and some calculations in page 137 of Olivier Debarre's book "Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry".